# PyInstaller. Run > pyinstaller myapp.spec from script works diffrent than from command line

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I've created a script to automatize creating new `executable` versions of my app. The thing is that when I run command `pyinstaller myapp.spec` from `commandline` on `windows` platform it creates different file  than when I run in from my script (which doesn't work BTW). Below is a snippet of code I use to create `.exe`.

**SNIPPET**

```
SPEC_PATH = 'venv_python37'
file = 'myapp.spec'

os.chdir(SPEC_PATH) 
command = r'{} {}'.format('pyinstaller', file)
os.system(command)
```

When I run that I see all prints of pyinstaller and at the end there is a:

```
55830 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Which looks exacly like when I run this command directly from `commandline`.

**DIFFERENCES**

1. `myapp.exe` size created from my script  is 27MB but from `commandline` it is 40MB
2. When I run the `.exe` created from `myscript` there is an error that says:

   The 'gcloud' distribution was not found and it is required by the application

That looks like when I run it from `myscrip` it user another dependencies than from `commandline` and I think `command` from `myscript` doesn't use dependencies from my `virtual enviroment`. A'm I right?

**MYAPP.SPEC**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew
block_cipher = None


_excludes=("'tcl'", "'tk'", "'FixTk'", "'_tkinter'", "'tkinter'", "'Tkinter'")

a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\Patryk\\PycharmProjects\\myapp\\myapp.py'],
             pathex=['venv_python37', 'C:\\Users\\Patryk\\PycharmProjects\\myapp'],
             binaries=None,
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=_excludes,
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
          name='BajotWorkSpace',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
      icon='C:\\Users\\Patryk\\PycharmProjects\\myapp\\main_logo.ico' )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
        Tree('C:\\Users\\Patryk\\PycharmProjects\\myapp\\Added_files'),               
        name='myapp')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. When I run `.spec` from my script it uses packages from my `virtual enviroment` but the same command run from `commandline` uses `global packages`. The issue with `gcloud` module was lack of hook file in `Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks`. Adding file named `hook-gcloud.py` with below code made my `.exe` work.

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('gcloud')
```